# For Loop with Nested If Statements

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to build a VBA tool to search for a specific text string (e.g. "Salary") in each row, copy the adjacent value, and paste it in a specified range in the next empty cell. However if the specific text string is not found in the rows, I want the tool to paste "NULL" in the next empty cell in the specified range.

This is what I have so far, but I think I have messed up the syntax for the loop and if statements. I am new to VBA and can't figure out how to fix it:

```vba
Sub IF_Statement_test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:B4")

For Each row In rng.Rows
 
If row.Cells.Find(What:="Salary") = True Then
  row.Cells.Find(What:="Salary").Offset(0, 1).Copy
  Range("A8").Find(What:="Salary").Offset(0, 1).Select
  If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
   Range("A8:E8").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
  Else
  If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
   ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
  ElseIf row.Cells.Find(What:="Salary") = False Then
    Range("A8").Find(What:="Salary").Offset(0, 1).Select
  If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
    Range("A8:E8").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = "NULL"
  ElseIf IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
   ActiveCell.Value = "NULL"
 End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next
End Sub
```

Essentially what I am trying to achieve overall is loop through each of the rows in the "A" section while looking for specific values as denoted in the "B" section. Once the specific values have been found in the "A" section, then paste it in the correct column and cell in the "B" section.

[image]

The below is an extract of the code I am currently using to achieve this. However, it does not meet the objective as mentioned in the first part of the question:

```vba
Sub Loop_Testing()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:GX14")


For Each row In rng.Rows
  
  On Error Resume Next
    
    'Employee Code
    row.Cells.Find(What:="Code").Offset(0, 1).Copy
    Range("A28:A45").Find(What:="Employee Code", LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Select
      If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
       Range("A29:Q29").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
       Else
       ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
       End If
    
    
    'ID Number
    row.Cells.Find(What:="Number").Offset(0, 1).Copy
    Range("A28:A45").Find(What:="ID Number", LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Select
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
     Range("A31:Q31").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
     ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0"
     Else
     ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
     ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0"
     End If

On Error GoTo 0

Next row

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You have 3 `IF` statements but only one `END IF`, you need an `END IF` for every `IF` (not for an `ELSEIF` though).

Comment: Can I put all the ``END IF`` statements right at the end? and should they be indented?

Comment: Just curious, I don't see "Salary" in your sample image section A within Range("A1:B4") ? Anyway, from the look at your image ... I think you mean something like this (just simple example) : section A: 4 column header NAME, CODE, ID, SALARY (A1:D1) with 3 rows of data (A2:D4) : aaa, bbb, ccc for NAME .... 1,2,3 for CODE, 11,12,13 for ID and 100,blank,300 for SALARY. Section B cell A11:A13 has value EMP CODE, ID NUM, SALARY MONTH X. Expected result : B10:D10 value aaa, bbb, ccc .... B11:D11 value 1,2,3 .... B12:D12 value 11,12,13 .... B13:D13 value 100, NULL, 300. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Can you use an Excel table for this?  Is your data exported from somewhere so that it always appears "raw" like this?  I might not have full context for what you're trying to do here, but I think you could solve this with a combination of Excel tables and the `LOOKUP` function.

Comment: I like the hand-drawn graphic :-) Some advice: try being strict about lining up if's and end-if's, and tabbing or spacing inside, like the answers below are all doing. Something as simple as some kind of logical whitespace structure helps reduce cognitive load even when reading your own code and is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think what you want is to find all of the fields listed in B (not just the salary; that's only an example) in the Payslip data in A, for each of the payslips. And your payslip data are supposed to be rows with a field name in one column and the corresponding value in the adjacent column.

And if all of that is correct, you'd like the output to be like the green section in the picture. (I've taken some liberty in creating the illustration just to simplify. It doesn't match your data exactly.)

If your data actually match your description, the subroutine below will fill in that table according to my understanding. If your field names match the payslip data exactly, the problem would be pretty simple.

The sub loops through the rows of payslips. For each payslip, it looks for each of the field names in your list of names. If it finds a match, it reads the following cell's value and writes it to the output section. The sub runs with my data as in the picture, and fills in the output section. (It skips the first 2 fields because we know they don't exist.)

[image: Spreadsheet with inputs and outputs]

However, your payslip data and your fields don't match well at all. The differences make the problem far more difficult, maybe intractable. For example, the field "Employee name and surname" does not exist in the payslip data. Instead it's listed as "Emp." and "Name" in 2 separate fields. That means it cannot be found like this. Furthermore, the values of those fields are offset by several columns. They're not the "adjacent" value as your question states.

If you can arrange your payslip data and your field names so that they match, and you have field name in one column and its value in the adjacent column, the sub will yield the output in my picture.

If you are stuck with the data format you've provided, this sub will not solve your problem, and your problem will be far more difficult.

```
Sub ExtractValues()
    Dim rngPayslips As Range, wkshSource As Worksheet, strTarget As String, rngField As Range, rngFieldNames As Range, rngCell As Range, rngRow As Range
    Dim nRowSource As Integer, nRowOut As Integer, nColOut As Integer, vntValue As Variant, bFound As Boolean
    
    Set wkshSource = ActiveSheet
    Set rngPayslips = wkshSource.Range("a1:r3")
    Set rngFieldNames = wkshSource.Range("a9:a11") ' Skip fields that don't exist
    nColOut = 1
    
    ' Look at each Payslip
    For Each rngRow In rngPayslips.Rows
        ' Look for each desired field within the payslip
        For Each rngField In rngFieldNames.Cells
            strTarget = rngField.Value
            bFound = False
            
            ' Look at each field in the current payslip for this field
            For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells
                If rngCell.Value = strTarget Then
                    vntValue = rngCell.Offset(0, 1) ' Found the value
                    bFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next rngCell
            
            ' Output
            If bFound = True Then
                rngField.Offset(0, nColOut) = vntValue
            Else
                rngField.Offset(0, nColOut) = "NULL" ' Null string or NULL?
            End If
        Next rngField
        
        ' Next output column for the next payslip
        nColOut = nColOut + 1
    Next rngRow
End Sub
```

EDIT:
If you have control over your input data and field names, this solution works. As an illustration, the below picture shows payslip rows (A) with field names in a single column (not spread over multiple columns), their values in the adjacent columns, and the names matching the list of fields in B.

[image: Sample data example]

[EDIT 2]
OK, got it. It looks like you're checking for an empty cell in the OUTPUT range ("A28:A45"). That's where the problem is.

Let's look at your "ID Number" section.

When you find the OUTPUT row for ID Number, the code `Range("A31:Q31").End(xlToRight)`
takes you to the last non-empty cell. Then the `.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial` pastes into the next cell to the right, the first empty cell. If Employee 2 had no entry, Employee 2 will be given Employee 3's ID Number, because Employee 2 had the first empty cell.

Instead, keep track of the output column explicitly with `nColOut` , and paste using `.Offset(0, nColOut)`. Then with each new pay slip, increment `nColOut = nColOut + 1`. That gives you total control over the output column. Every entry for Employee x will be offset x columns from column A. It won't matter whether Employee 2's cell was empty, your output for Employee 3 will be in Employee 3's column.

The tail end of my code (under the Output comment) does exactly that.

Comment: Okay so basically I do not have any control over the outputted data. I do not use the section B fields to search within section A. I use custom words to find the values required in the payslip data in column A. I then also use custom words to paste the retrieved value in section B. This is all working perfectly as is, it is the piece of code below my question posted -- 1/2

Comment: All I need added to my existing code is the function for the code to paste NULL if ,for example, a salary value is not found in the payslip data for a specific employee and to move on. What is currently happening if, for example the salary value is not found for employee 1, the code is pasting the salary value for employee 2 for employee 1. I hope I  am making sense

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the first time around. My EDIT 2 should do what you want. Take control of the output column instead of just looking for an empty cell. Good luck!

Comment: And of course, don't forget ```nColOut = 1``` before starting the loop. Otherwise it will be zero and will overwrite the labels in Column A.

Comment: So did it work when you tested it? If so, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 8):

### Find String

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindString()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A1:B4")

    Dim dCell As Range:
    Set dCell = ws.Cells(8, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
    
    Dim srrg As Range, sCell As Range
    
    For Each srrg In srg.Rows
        Set sCell = srrg.Find("Salary", , , xlWhole)
        If sCell Is Nothing Then
            dCell.Value = "NULL"
        Else
            dCell.Value = sCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(, 1)
    Next srrg

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This works to find the string. However I see it automatically pastes in the 8th row. What I need to do is find "salary" in the row and then paste that value in another part of the sheet. The range in which the "salary" value should be pasted should also be identified by a text identifier such as "salary value" and then paste the copied amount in the next empty cell. I hope I am making sense!

Comment: `Null` is a value that might be returned from a database and is represented as VarType 1 (`vbNull`). If you write such a value into a cell, it will be empty. Reading that empty value back into VBA get an VarType 0 (`vbEmpty`). As far as I know, there is no `Null`-value in Excel.

Comment: @FunThomas Thx. Being stupid again, totally forgot that `#NULL!` is an error type. Fixed it. Don't remove the comment though.

Comment: Where and in what way should I look for the Salary matching occurrences? Can there even be more than one in the first range? Explain it in more detail, e.g. starting from row 8, each will be in one row... Maybe share an example screenshot.

Comment: @VBasic2008, okay I have updated the question to include some more detail. Hopefully that provides clarity on what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @VBasic2008 any chance you're able to provide a solution given the updated code? would be much appreciated man!

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub IF_Statement_test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim salary As Variant
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim destRow As Long
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:B4")
    destRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Salary Value", , , xlWhole).row
    
    For Each row In rng.Rows
        'find the salary value
        Set cell = row.Find("Salary", , , xlWhole)
        If cell Is Nothing Then
            salary = "Null"
        Else
            salary = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
        
        
        lastColumn = Cells(destRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
        Cells(destRow, lastColumn + 1).Value = salary
        
    Next row
    
End Sub
```

Comment: this code unfortunately does not look for "Salary" in the "B section" (as per the updated information in the question. it is currently looking for any text field containing "Salary" and pasting values alongside, which is not what I am trying to do

Comment: You could do a double `For` loop. For each piece of information you need to gather in section B, then for each employee in section A, look for the information you need then put it into section B.

Comment: Are you able to show an example of how that would work perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this (not tested):

```
If row.Cells.Find(What:="Salary") = True Then
  row.Cells.Find(What:="Salary").Offset(0, 1).Copy
  Range("A8").Find(What:="Salary").Offset(0, 1).Select
  If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
   Range("A8:E8").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
  ElseIf IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
  ElseIf row.Cells.Find(What:="Salary") = False Then
    Range("A8").Find(What:="Salary").Offset(0, 1).Select
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
      Range("A8:E8").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = "NULL"
    ElseIf IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
      ActiveCell.Value = "NULL"
    End If
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Sorry I downvoted it by mistake so upvoted to remove the downvote lol. I tried the code now but unfortunately it does not work. As it is getting stuck as soon as "Salary" is not present in the search range - this is the problem I am having here. I want it to paste NULL and then move on

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub SubExtractData()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim RngSourceRow As Range
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim RngResultHeaders As Range
    Dim DblEmployeeIndex As Double
    Dim DblStatIndex As Double
    Dim StrWhatStat As String
    Dim VarResult() As Variant
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngSource = Range("A1:GX14") '<-CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY
    Set RngResultHeaders = Range("A7:A11") '<-CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY
    
    'Redeclaring VarResult and setting RngResult to suit the data.
    ReDim VarResult(1 To RngResultHeaders.Rows.Count + 1, 1 To RngSource.Rows.Count)
    Set RngResult = RngResultHeaders.Offset(-1, 1).Resize(UBound(VarResult, 1), UBound(VarResult, 2))
    
    'Checking if RngResult already contains data.
    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(RngResult) <> RngResult.Cells.Count Then
        
        'Ask the user if the data in RngResult shouldn't be overwritten.
        If MsgBox("The result will be reported in range " & vbLf & vbLf & RngResult.Address(0, 0, xlA1, True) & vbLf & vbLf & "Any data already in it will be overwritten." & vbLf & vbLf & "Continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNoCancel, "Data already there") <> vbYes Then
            
            'Notify the user.
            MsgBox "No list has been reported", vbOKOnly, "Macro interrupted as specified"
            
            'Exit the macro.
            Exit Sub
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
    'Setting DblEmployeeIndex.
    DblEmployeeIndex = 0
    
    'Covering each row in RngSource.
    For Each RngSourceRow In RngSource.Rows
        
        'Setting DblEmployeeIndex for the next employee.
        DblEmployeeIndex = DblEmployeeIndex + 1
        
        'Reporting the header for the employee.
        VarResult(1, DblEmployeeIndex) = RngSource.Cells(DblEmployeeIndex, 1)
        
        'Covering each stat.
        For DblStatIndex = 1 To RngResultHeaders.Rows.Count
            
            'Setting StrWhatStat as the stat to be searched.
            StrWhatStat = RngResultHeaders(DblStatIndex, 1)
            
            'Checking if the stat is not reported in the row.
            If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngSourceRow, StrWhatStat) = 0 Then
                
                'Reporting NULL.
                VarResult(DblStatIndex + 1, DblEmployeeIndex) = "NULL"
                
            Else
                
                'Reporting the stat.
                VarResult(DblStatIndex + 1, DblEmployeeIndex) = RngSourceRow.Cells(1, Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(StrWhatStat, RngSourceRow, 0) + 1).Value2
                
            End If
            
        Next
        
    Next
    
    'Clear the contents of RngResult.
    RngResult.ClearContents
    
    'Report VarResult in RngResult.
    RngResult.Value2 = VarResult
    
End Sub
```

Make sure you change the setting of RngSource to match the range of data containings the rows with the "raw" data and the setting of RngResultHeaders to match the column with all the stats in the report.